# ListView and Tabwidget in Fragment

Tags: java, android

Below is a part of my code:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
```

How do i make HomeFragment listview or tab widget.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_scroll, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

if i should extends listfragment, the line:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

flag an error: `"The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, HomeFragment)"`

please, how do i make this work, and how do i still add a tab widget assuming i do not want to make it listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

You cannot do like this `Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();` if you do that you will get `Can not convert HomeFragment to Fragment` because `HomeFragment` is fragment class so you cannot assign that into a `Fragment`. So,you have to like `HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();` For example from your code.

```
switch (position) {
        case 0:
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();

            if (fragment != null) {
                  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                  // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                  mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                  mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                  setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                  // error in creating fragment
                  Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
            break;

            // do like this for remaining cases

        default:
            break;
        }
```